# Executing a callback function based on routes in angular (no navigation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

We have a app with, among other stuff, lists of things. In this web app, we have a custom jQuery plugin, that we apply to the lists, which shows a context menu for the clicked table row. In some cases, it makes sense to let the user interact with *related* objects through these context menus, for example clicking on a row in a list of projects, and selecting *edit project manager*, should take me to the `edit user` page for the user that's assigned as the project manager to that project.

Within an AngularJS app, this is quite simple: clicking the context menu just takes me to the route corresponding to the action I want to take, and routing handles the rest.

However, this is a (very...) large web application, and only small parts of it are written with AngularJS; we also need to support custom callback functions from the context menu. Sometimes we want to open a popup window with a different url, sometimes we want to make a custom AJAX call, sometimes we want to do something else...

The configuration of the context menu - what elements are displayed etc - is done on the server, and passed to the client as JSON. Thus, I can't specify a callback function on the configuration object directly, but I'm limited to strings and other JSON-representable things.

I had hoped to be able to do this simply by configuring a route and saying "when I go to this route, call this here function and abort navigation", and then specify a url template on the config object. However, this doesn't seem trivial, and [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890784/fire-a-callback-when-route-is-changed-animations-loaders-etc-in-angularjs) [attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765719/how-to-watch-for-a-route-change-in-angularjs) [I can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event) [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384134/how-to-call-a-function-in-angularjs-when-route-matches) seem to be deeply interlinked with navigating to a specific controller and/or view somewhere; I haven't found anything that helps me understand how to perform a *general JavaScript action* based on a route.

**Is there a way to use Angular routing to call general callback functions, without any navigation?**

---

**UPDATE**

Given the comments, I'm a little worried that it might have been [better to state this problem differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so here is another try:

Given a JSON object that I fetch from the server *(note: **not** a full-fledged javascript object - no properties can be `function`s, for example)*, how can I map a property on the object to a function call on the client, using as little custom code as possible (in other words, using Angular for as much as possible)?

Comment: Can you not just set up a method in the controller you are using? I use the ui-router and am able to set up a 'resolve' method on the state/view change that works great for this purpose.

Comment: @beauXjames: We're using the regular `ngRoute` module - am I understanding you correctly that I need to switch to [this project](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to get this working? I'm a little reluctant to do so, because of this quote from their readme: `**Note:** UI-Router is under active development. As such, while this library is well-tested, the API may change. Consider using it in production applications only if you're comfortable following a changelog and updating your usage accordingly.`

Comment: there may be other ways to go about solving your problem...ui-router happens to be a pretty simple migration, though...I understand the 'under development' clause, but what isn't these days?

Comment: did you try http interceptors?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov: I'm not sure http interceptors will solve this problem either, since what I want to intercept this long before it comes to the $http service. If I'm wrong, feel free to write up an answer that shows me why! ;)