# How start route in controller Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I need that code will be called in controller `ChatController`, not in global application:

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.when("/chat/dialog/:id",
                {
                    templateUrl: "/template/chat/active_dialog.html",
                    controller: "ChatController"
                }
            );
        })
```

How I can do it?

I tried (template is not loaded in div):

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.selectDialog = function (id, event){
   $scope.template = '/template/chat/active_dialog.html';
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-include src="{{template}}"></div>
```

Comment: Seems similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384134/how-to-call-a-function-in-angularjs-when-route-matches .Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: could you be a little more specific? what do you mean with "not in global application"? Do you want to define the Route in the controller (not possible)?

Comment: Yes, I want to define route in Controller, is it not possible? How I can load template then?

Comment: the `$routeProvider` is just accesable in the config phase of the application, that means you cant use the `$routeProvider` in controllers. The template is loadet automaticly from the url you set in `templateUrl`

Comment: you could create a separate module for this? I imagine you would need to create a third module for anything shared between modules.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Nano,all the providers that are used angular are **injected** and used in 
**.config**,you directly cannot use it in your controller.

Comment: Are you calling this function $scope.selectDialog()?